# Delay in exiting VBScript after exiting excel in the script

Tags: excel, vbscript, ms-word

The following is a fragment of a larger VBScript annotated to demonstrate/explain the problem.

```
  Set oShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

' On exiting Excel or any other MSOffice product, 
' Taskmanager entry disappears immediately but oshell.run exits consistently 20 seconds later!
  oShell.Run "EXCEL.EXE /safe",3,True ' Doesn't matter if Safe mode is used or not.
  wscript.echo "Shell exit after Excel is closed." ' Echoes 20 seconds after Excel is closed.

' However, on exiting Notepad or Paint etc.,
' Taskmanager entry disappears immediately and oshell.run exits immediately!
  oShell.Run "NOTEPAD.EXE",3,True
  wscript.echo "Shell exit after Notepad closed" ' Echoes immediately after Notepad is closed.
```

I want the Shell to exit immediately the application is closed.
This has only recently started happening.
Any ideas why this might be happening and how it might be fixed?

Thanks... Grant.

Comment: Excel isn't shutting down for 20 secs.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  Are you suggesting that Excel is still shutting down for 20 seconds after it has disappeared from task manager? This has only recently started happening. The script is several years old and has worked perfectly for years.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your script. Look into Excel

Comment: Thanks Mark. The invocation of excel is bare bones i.e. / safe mode and it still happens. No XLSTART etc. Any ideas as to what I should be looking for within excel?

Comment: Not really, the file that is open. Autosave (if excel has one like word) it will register itself in the ROT (that how you find open COM programs and Documents). Run Process Monitor from sysinternals (Part of MS). Only look at what is happening in that 20 seconds. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon

Comment: One other thing another program is waiting on it. A zombie process is one that has fully exited but something is holding it handle open. So the handle your script is waiting on remains valid till released.